# SQL Server CTE Bottom to Top Recursive with Where clause

Tags: sql-server, cte, hierarchy, recursive

I have an Employee Table with an EmployeeId, ManagerId and a Name field.

The goal is to make a recursive With fetching all the rows from an employee to the top manager (ManagerId is null).

[I found this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001270/data-structures-available-in-sql-server-2008/7028417) which helped to get the base of the code but I do not manage to make it work for my case

```
DECLARE @EmployeeTable table ([EmployeeId] int, [name] varchar(10), [managerId] int)
INSERT @EmployeeTable VALUES (1,'Jerome', NULL )  -- tree is as follows:
INSERT @EmployeeTable VALUES (2,'Joe'   ,1)     --                      1-Jerome
INSERT @EmployeeTable VALUES (3,'Paul'  ,2)     --                     /        \
INSERT @EmployeeTable VALUES (4,'Jack'  ,3)     --              2-Joe               9-Bill
INSERT @EmployeeTable VALUES (5,'Daniel',3)     --            /       \                  \
INSERT @EmployeeTable VALUES (6,'David' ,2)     --     3-Paul          6-David       10-Sam
INSERT @EmployeeTable VALUES (7,'Ian'   ,6)     --    /      \            /    \
INSERT @EmployeeTable VALUES (8,'Helen' ,6)     -- 4-Jack  5-Daniel   7-Ian    8-Helen
INSERT @EmployeeTable VALUES (9,'Bill ' ,1)     --
INSERT @EmployeeTable VALUES (10,'Sam'  ,9)     --

DECLARE @employeeId int = 3

;WITH StaffTree AS
(
    SELECT 
        c.[EmployeeId], c.[name], c.managerId, 0 AS [Level]
        FROM @EmployeeTable c
        LEFT OUTER JOIN @EmployeeTable  cc ON c.managerId=cc.EmployeeId
        WHERE c.EmployeeId=@employeeId OR (@employeeId IS NULL AND     c.managerId IS NULL)
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            s.[EmployeeId], s.[name], s.managerId, t.[Level]+1
        FROM StaffTree t
            INNER JOIN @EmployeeTable s ON t.[EmployeeId]=s.managerId
        WHERE s.managerId=@employeeId OR @employeeId IS NULL OR t.Level>1
)
SELECT * FROM StaffTree
```

In case you select the employee 3 hierarchy, the result should be:

```
EmployeeId | Name    | ManagerId 
1          | Jerome  | NULL
2          | Joe     | 1
3          | Paul    | 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Swapping the columns in the inner join in the recursive part is a way to go about this.**

Join columns changed from `t.[EmployeeId]=s.managerId` to `s.[EmployeeId]=t.managerId`

*I deleted some parts that did not seem like they were needed.*

```
DECLARE @employeeId int = 3

;WITH StaffTree AS
(
    SELECT 
        c.[EmployeeId], c.[name], c.managerId, 0 AS [Level]
        FROM @EmployeeTable c
        WHERE c.EmployeeId=@employeeId OR (@employeeId IS NULL AND     c.managerId IS NULL)
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            s.[EmployeeId], s.[name], s.managerId, t.[Level]+1
        FROM StaffTree t
        INNER JOIN @EmployeeTable s ON s.[EmployeeId]=t.managerId
)
SELECT EmployeeId,
       name,
       managerId 
FROM StaffTree
ORDER BY managerId asc;
```

**Result**

```
EmployeeId  name    managerId
1           Jerome  NULL
2           Joe     1
3           Paul    2
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you had a tiny error when copying the example that you linked to -

```
c.[EmployeeId], c.[name], c.managerId, 0 AS [Level]
```

should be

```
c.[EmployeeId], c.[name], c.managerId, 1 AS [Level]
```

Once I make that change, your code functions the same way as the example.